# TCHAR incompatible with LPSTR

Tags: c++, casting

Argument type of TCHAR is incompatible with parameter type LPSTR.

How do I solve this? I've tried convering/casting the type to no avail

```
void getHWID()
{
// GetVolumeInformationA
DWORD DriveSerial;

// GetComputerNameA
LPSTR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
DWORD size = sizeof(ComputerName) / sizeof(ComputerName[0]);
// OS GUID
HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
DWORD OsGUID;
GetVolumeInformationA(0, nullptr, '\0', &DriveSerial, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
GetComputerNameA(ComputerName, &size);
GetCurrentHwProfileA(&hwProfileInfo);
memcpy(&OsGUID, &hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid, sizeof(hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid)); 
};
```

Comment: Your program should work if you just change `LPSTR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];` to `TCHAR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1];`

Comment: @SergeBallesta except `UNICODE` build is enabled...

Comment: Writing code that was appropriate in the previous century is fraught with trouble.  The type of hwProfileInfo is wrong, needs to be HW_PROFILE_INFOA.  The memcpy() call is quite wrong, szHwProfileGuid is a string and not a DWORD.  Throw it away, write this century's version.

Comment: @HansPassant *'that was appropriate in the previous century'* - if facing WinAPI directly (well, it actually is a C API...) it should still be appropriate even today – or have I missed something having fundamentally changed the last years (apart from UWP...)?

Answer (score -1):

Change `LPSTR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];` to `CHAR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];`

`LPSTR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];` the type of `ComputerName` is a `LPSTR` *array* but not `LPSTR`.

Comment: Actually: `CHAR`, not `TCHAR`: the `[...]A` functions are called explicitly, these expect `CHAR*` (`LPSTR`). `TCHAR ` won't be equivalent if `UNICODE` build is enabled...

Comment: good point, But I prefer to use `TCHAR` and `[...]` to compatible with Unicode and non-Unicode

Answer (score -1):

You should use `CHAR[]` for `ComputerName`:

```
CHAR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
```

Answer (score -1):

WinAPI uses `CHAR`, `WCHAR` and `TCHAR`. `CHAR` always maps to normal `char`, `WCHAR` to `wchar_t`.

`TCHAR` depends on compiler settings, though: in a `UNICODE` build, it is equivalent to `WCHAR` and in non-`UNICODE` to `CHAR`.

Analogously, there's `LPSTR`, `LPWSTR` and `LPTSTR`, these are pointers to their respective `XCHAR` counter parts (`L`ong `P`ointer). You should always use the appropriate pairs:

- `CHAR` and `LPSTR`
- `WCHAR` and `LPWSTR`
- `TCHAR` and`LPTSTR`

Side note: In my personal code, I would never using those worthless `*STR` macros, instead I'd directly use `[W|T]CHAR [const]*`...

With above information:

```
LPSTR ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
// is equivalent to:
CHAR* ComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
//  ^
```

Pretty likely not what you intended...